# How to allow apps to take screenshots in wayland when denied first time?

Tags: linux, fedora, wayland, screenshot

I used to use flameshot in my Fedora on Wayland(Gnome). When i first launched it via "flameshot gui" the system asked whether i allow flameshot to take screenshots or something like that i clicked yes and everything worked.
This time when i installed fedora, flameshot and launched it i accidentally clicked "Esc" and the prompt was closed. So i tried launching it again, but no prompt was showed again, instead i only see this error.

```
 $ flameshot gui

flameshot: error: Unable to capture screen
flameshot: error: Unable to capture screen
flameshot: info: Screenshot aborted.
```

How can i allow flameshot to take screenshots again? I tried reinstalling the app, but it didn't work. I can theoretically reinstall the whole OS, but that just seem a bit of an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: The **[second answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/754879/583574)** turned out to be better.

--

(Unfortunately, I cannot write this as comment.)

The option is likely saved in some config file. Beside handwork searching, you may try

```
find ~/.config  -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i 'flameshot' | less
```

and similar.

```
find ~          -type f  -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i 'flameshot' | less
```

may generate too much output or take much time, but may be very much useful after you create a new user AND make the unfortunate `Esc` choice.

Replacing `grep` with `grep -a` produces more output for binary files, but harder to interpret.

Comment: The thing with GNOME is that most settings are stored in the dconf database, which uses a binary format and can't be grepped directly

Comment: @muru: That perhaps could be covered by `dconf dump / | grep -i flameshot` and/or `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i flameshot` ?

Comment: Possibly, but I don't know if this setting is stored per-app, or if there's a allow-list with names of apps in them

Comment: No, it seems to be buried in dbus / dbus-portal. To that it might be loaded from some .conf file.

Answer (score 0):

**UDATE**: #3 turned to be the way -- With two improvements possible, both implied by the solution discused [here](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/how-to-allow-apps-to-take-screenshots-in-wayland/87922/2) and copied here in the answer of @Hayk: 1. Instead of setting the option, one can just make reset and let GUI ask the question again 2. Istead of the `python3` script, one can communicate directly with dbus through

```
dbus-save ... DeletePermission ...
```

for doing the reset and

```
dbus-save ... Lookup
```

for checking the current setting (say, before making the action, then after, and then after answering GUI's question)

A documentation for `org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore` can be found at https://github.com/endlessm/flatpak/blob/master/data/org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore.xml.
(Does this mean that it is a Flatpak thing?).
In particular, `List` seems to be useful:

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply=literal --dest=org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore /org/freedesktop/impl/portal/PermissionStore org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore.List string:'screenshot'
# For me, it outputs      array [ ]
```

--

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

Try this:

1. Go to Applications in Settings, find the application, and switch on the  `Screenshots` permission somewhere under `Notifications` permission.
2. Or try to start Flatseal (cf. [link](https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal)) and find the application there.
3. This seems to address your problem: [link](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/issues/2868#issuecomment-1384310540) / [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437027/how-to-reset-screenshot-permissions-for-an-app-on-ubuntu-22-10). Is it `python3` script.
   More at [link](https://community.upwork.com/t5/Freelancers/Constantly-asking-for-permission-to-share-screenshot-on-Gnome/m-p/1222388#M731300). It does not name Flameshot, so it is probably an `allow=all` type setting about screentshots.
4. Even if this will not work, at least the following links might help or motivate searching
   [something added](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/issues/649#issuecomment-1249081784) //
   [link1](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/issues/2868#issuecomment-1212429625) // [link2](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/issues/1910#issuecomment-1023925922) //
   [something merged](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/merge_requests/1954)

Did anything help?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the  time, but there is no other permission option other than notifications

Comment: No need to thank, but you can upwote the answer. Reminder: Be so kind and accept an anwer to make clear the question was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked this question in the official fedora forum as well and got a perfect answer:

> Ok, don’t ask me more.  I’m not an expert and
> the topic seems a bit tangled. Such permission seems to be stored on
> some `xdg-desktop-portal` (?) database, key/value store. Whatever. You
> can interact with it using dbus. There is also a GUI `qt-qdbusviewer`,
> but it doesn’t look so simple. However.
>
> From the command line, the reply to this command
>
> ```
> dbus-send --session --print-reply=literal \
>   --dest=org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore /org/freedesktop/impl/portal/PermissionStore \
>     org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore.Lookup string:'screenshot'
> ```
>
> string:`screenshot` in your case probably is
>
> ```
>    array [
>       dict entry(
>                   array [
>             no         ]
>       )    ]    variant       byte 0
> ```
>
> You should put it to “yes”.
>
> Well, this Python script Solved: Re: Constantly asking for permission
> to share... - Upwork Community seems to do the job.
>
> However you could “reset” such PermissionStore with this command
>
> ```
> dbus-send --session --print-reply=literal
>     --dest=org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore /org/freedesktop/impl/portal/PermissionStore \
>     org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore.DeletePermission \
>     string:'screenshot' string:'screenshot' string:''
> ```
>
> Now
>
> ```
> dbus-send --session --print-reply=literal
> --dest=org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore /org/freedesktop/impl/portal/PermissionStore
> org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore.Lookup string:'screenshot'
> string:'screenshot'
> ```
>
> returns
>
> ```
>   array [    ]    variant       byte 0
> ```
>
> And now relaunch flameshot gui and the spoke asking the permission for
> applications to take screenshots should appear again. This time select
> “Allow”.
>
> If you look at such value again:
>
> ```
> dbus-send --session --print-reply=literal
> --dest=org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore /org/freedesktop/impl/portal/PermissionStore
> org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore.Lookup string:'screenshot'
> string:'screenshot'
> ```
>
> Now the result should be:
>
> ```
>    array [
>       dict entry(
>                   array [
>             yes         ]
>       )    ]    variant       byte 0
> ```

The formatting doesn't look good here(well, because i couldn't make it look good), so better head over to the forum and read the original there -
https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/how-to-allow-apps-to-take-screenshots-in-wayland/87922/2